# The division of a city in terms of the driving distance to two places.

Tags: routes, traffic-simulation

For a research project I would like to divide the travel times within a city between two places. Specifically: It is about the question in which of two hospitals an ambulance within the city limits of Munich, Germany should drive best, i.e. what has the shortest travel time. Is there a way to calculate this? I have to say that I am a doctor and unfortunately have no programming knowledge. So I need a lot of support ;-) Many thanks already

Answer (score 0):

The best and the easiest way i can suggest is you can calculate the Arial distance between source and destination using Latitude and longitude and which ever is short you can take that in consideration. Because to determine the minimum time there are loads of dimension facts are involved. eg. Number of traffic,Is any short curt available, Road conditions, Avg. vehicle moving speed etc. 
Sample code in **JAVASCRIPT**

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

i am attaching alink from where you can get the details.
[link1](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)
[Link2](https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/)